# When do solutions exist to variational problems in classical mechanics?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Suppose I have a configuration space $ M $ and a lagrangian $ L: TM \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. The action functional is defined as
$$
\mathcal{S}[q(t)] = \int_0^T L(\dot q(t) ) \ dt ,
$$
The principle of least action states that the trajectory starting from $ q_i $ at time $ t_i $ and arriving at $ q_f $ at time $ t_f $ is the path minimizing the action subject to the boundary conditions $ q(t_i) = q_i $ and $ q(t_f) = q_f $.

My question is: when do solutions to the principle of least action exist?  What conditions on $ M $ and $ L$ ensure that solutions exist for all boundary conditions $ (q_i, t_i) , (q_f, t_f) $?

Comment: It's named "principle of least action" because it was first stated for mechanics problem where the extremum is usually a minimum, but it was later extended to extrema in general (e.g. in special and general relativity the variational formulations get the maximum for (all?) the functionals). Anyway, the question, in this so general form you've stated, needs something more than an answer here. You can find very iteresting papers and texts googling a ittle.